# Why is the group ring just a ring, not a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can one give an example showing that it is not a field? I think the essential problem is to show that there exists some element in the ring without an inverse?

Comment: Almost **every** example gives a ring which is not a field. What have you tried in order to do this? I suggest you take the smallest non-trivial group and find all the invertible elements in its group ring.

Comment: @Nan, have you tried googling? It is usually not a great idea to ask questions to which there is a Wikipedia page exclusively dedicated — unless you make the question more precise and tell us what you do not understand in it, for example. The purpose of this site is not to rewrite Wikipedia!

Comment: For example, $2\in \mathbb Z[G]$ has no inverse. Also, group rings for non-abelian groups  are not abelian, so the best you could hope for would be a skew field anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Group rings are rarely ever even a simple ring. An easy way to see this is that (when $|G|>1$) the augmentation ideal (generated by the elements of the form $g-1$) is always a nontrivial ideal.